# Prerender.io throws socket error

Tags: angularjs, sockets, prerender

I have been trying to make prerender.io working for a week now, I tried everything but nothing worked.

I have a node server:

```
'use strict';
var path = require('path');
var _ = require('lodash');
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express();

var prerender = require('prerender-node')
   .set('prerenderToken', 'My Key');

// These search engine bot do not adheres to google's _escaped_fragment_
// proposal, so we use user agent to detect them.
var moreCrawlerUserAgents = [
  'Slurp!',
  'MSNBot',
  'YoudaoBot',
  'JikeSpider',
  'Sosospider',
  '360Spider',
  'Sogou web spider',
  'Sogou inst spider',
  'baiduspider',
  'facebookexternalhit',
  'twitterbot',
  'rogerbot',
  'linkedinbot',
  'embedly',
  'quora link preview',
  'showyoubot',
  'outbrain',
  'pinterest',
  'developers.google.com/+/web/snippet',
  'slackbot',
  'vkShare',
  'W3C_Validator',
  'redditbot'
];
prerender.set('crawlerUserAgents', _.union(
  prerender.crawlerUserAgents, moreCrawlerUserAgents));
app.use(prerender);

var options = {
  maxAge: '60d',
   setHeaders: function(res, path, stat) {
    // Webfonts need to have CORS * set in order to work.
    if (path.match(/ttf|woff|woff2|eot|svg/ig)) {
      res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    }
  }
};

var dist_path = '/client/dist/';

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, dist_path), options));

app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + dist_path + '/index.html'));
});
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000; 
app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0');
console.log("Listening on port " + port);
```

It works fine until I pass _escaped_fragment_= as a query string parameter then it throws these two errors:

```
Error: getaddrinfo EMFILE
   at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
   at errnoException (dns.js:49:15)
   at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)
```

OR

```
Error: socket hang up
   at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:215:15)
   at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:300:23)
   at Socket.emit (events.js:129:20)
   at _stream_readable.js:908:16
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I don't know what the problem is, please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Those errors seem to point to some other issue. EMFILE means you have too many files open which is weird. Which version of Node and NPM are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your response,    
node v0.12.7  & 
npm 3.8.0

Comment: Is this happening when just testing a few requests? Or are you sending lots of requests per second? Can you try upgrading node locally and see if you get the same issue?

Comment: Thank you my friend, it was a firewall problem

Comment: I'm using iptables, is there anyway to make prerender and iptables work togother?

Comment: It should work fine as long as all of the networking config is set up correctly. Prerender just makes a regular http request.

Comment: Thank you my friend, it works fine now, our admin was blocking so many stuff.